# How can I show a results from query in hibernate to table in bootstrap?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, criteria

I have one project where i use a hibernate spring boot and i want to connect tow tables in one query and show the results in bootstrap table. i made the query and i take the results but it is in `List<Oject[]>` and i need it in `List<MyClass>` i think. So can someone help me how to do it...How to put query results in bootstrap table..?
The query is:

TableInfoDAO.java

```
         CriteriaBuilder builder = getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
         CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);

         Root<DocumentBean> rootDept = criteriaQuery.from(DocumentBean.class);
         Root<TableInfoBean> rootEmp = criteriaQuery.from(TableInfoBean.class);


         criteriaQuery.multiselect(rootDept,rootEmp);
         criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(rootDept.get("user_id"), rootEmp.get("id")));

         Query<Object[]> query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
         List<Object[]> resl = query.getResultList();
         for (Object[] objects : resl) {
                DocumentBean employee=(DocumentBean)objects[0];
                TableInfoBean department=(TableInfoBean)objects[1];
                System.out.println("EMP NAME="+department.getName()+"\t DEPT NAME="+employee.getNote());
             }
         acUsers =  (List<TableInfoBean>) (Object) resl;
```

And the tableInfo.jsp

```
<tbody>
        <c:set var="count" value="1" scope="page" />
           <c:forEach var="userActiv" items="${acUsers}">
                <tr>
                   <td class="center">${count}</td> 
                    <td>${userActiv.name}</td>
                    <td>${userActiv.lastname}</td>
                </tr>
          <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page"/>
        </c:forEach>
```

How to get results to the Bootstrap table....Thanks !

Comment: `i take the results but it is in List and i need it in List` what?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer i edit the question sorry...i want to put the results from Query to table, can you help me somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just change :

```
for (Object[] objects : result) {
                DocumentBean documentInfo=(DocumentBean)objects[0];
                TableInfoBean userInfo=(TableInfoBean)objects[1];
                System.out.println("Kelner="+userInfo.getName()+"\t Masa="+documentInfo.getNote());
                TableInfoBean zaedno = new TableInfoBean();
                zaedno.setLastname(documentInfo.getNote());
                zaedno.setName(userInfo.getName());
                userInformation.add(zaedno);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<tbody>
    <c:set var="count" value="1" scope="page" />
       <c:forEach var="userActiv" items="${acUsers}">
            <tr>
                <td class="center">${count}</td> 
                <td>${userActiv[0]}</td>
                <td>${userActiv[1]}</td>
            </tr>
      <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page"/>
</c:forEach>
```